# EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'test2' in [items | async

Tags: angular

In the process of debugging an application issue I created the simplified component below.  It gets the following exception when executed:

```
ingredient2service.ts:24 ["test1", "test2"]
angular2.dev.js:23093 EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'test2' in [items | async in Ingredient2SearchComponent@5:12]
angular2.dev.js:23083 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'test2'
```

My guess is its related to the data format returned by rawSearch, however I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**ingredient2search.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';
import {Ingredient2Service} from './ingredient2service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'ingredient-search',
  providers: [Ingredient2Service],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Ingredient2 Search</h2>
      <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="term"/>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Ingredient2SearchComponent {
  items: Observable<Array<string>>;
  term = new Control();
  constructor(private ingredient2Service: Ingredient2Service) {
    this.items = ingredient2Service.search(this.term.valueChanges);
  }
}
```

**ingredient2service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {URLSearchParams, Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


@Injectable()
export class Ingredient2Service {
getData = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  search(terms: Observable<string>, debounceDuration = 400) {
    return terms.debounceTime(debounceDuration)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.rawSearch(term));
  }

  rawSearch(term: string) {
    var getData = new Array();
    this.getData = ["test1", "test2"];
    console.log(this.getData);
    return this.getData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you should use the `map` operator instead of the `switchMap` one within the `search` method since the `rawSearch` method returns an array and not an observable:

```
search(terms: Observable<string>, debounceDuration = 400) {
  return terms.debounceTime(debounceDuration)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map(term => this.rawSearch(term));
}
```

If the `rawSearch` method returns an observable, it would work fine with your code. Here is a sample with a raw observable:

```
rawSearch(term: string) {
  var getData = new Array();
  this.getData = ["test1", "test2"];
  console.log(this.getData);
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.next(this.getData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Adding the observable to the return worked perfectly!  Thank You.  Don't I need to keep the switchmap to unsubscribe from a previous call when term changes within the debounce period?